# Duplicate partial line text with vi/vim

Tags: vim, vi

I have two lists like these below:

```
abc.domain.com
defg.domain.com
hijklmn.domain.com
```

```
abc.domain.com/sub/
defg.domain.com/anothersub/
hijklmn.domain.com/thirdsub/
```

I need to make these two lists appear like so:

```
abc.domain.com?ref=abc
defg.domain.com?ref=defg
hijklmn.domain.com?ref=hijklmn
```

```
abc.domain.com/sub/?ref=sub
defg.domain.com/anothersub/?ref=anothersub
hijklmn.domain.com/thirdsub/?ref=thirdsub
```

How to I accomplish this in vi/vim?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume the two lists are in two different buffers. We can do the job using vim's `:s` command:

### For list1:

```
%s/\v([^.]+).*/&?ref=\1/
```

### For list2:

```
%s#\v.*/([^/]+)/$#&?ref=\1#
```

If the two lists are mixed in one buffer, you can use `:g` command to do the substitution only on a certain target.